# Are there a better approach then defining many classes in typescript for knockout viewmodels

Tags: typescript

I have seperated out my viewmodels into classes using typescript.

Now in my Bootstraper i am importing them all like this:

```
import dl = module("DataLayer");
import vm1 = module("AppBarViewModel");
import vm2 = module("Nav2ViewModelCommander");
import vm3 = module("IdentityViewModel");
```

Are there not a way to collect them to one namespace?
I am using requirejs and my viewmodels look something like this when compiled to js.

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var AppBarViewModel = (function () {
        function AppBarViewModel() {
            this.visible = ko.observable(true);
            this.buttons = ko.observableArray([]);
            this.enableContext = ko.observable(true);
            this.canClose = ko.computed(function () {
                var k = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.buttons(), function (b) {
                    return b.blockHide && b.blockHide == true;
                });
                return k == null;
            });
        }
        AppBarViewModel.prototype.addButton = function (data) {
            this.buttons.push(data);
            this.visible(data.blockHide && data.blockHide == true);
        };
        AppBarViewModel.prototype.removeButton = function (data) {
            this.buttons.remove(data);
            this.visible(!this.canClose());
        };
        return AppBarViewModel;
    })();
    exports.AppBarViewModel = AppBarViewModel;    
})
```

from

```
///<reference path="../knockout.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../require.d.ts" />

declare var ko: any;

    export class AppBarViewModel {

        visible = ko.observable(true);
        buttons = ko.observableArray([]);

        enableContext = ko.observable(true);
        addButton(data) {
            this.buttons.push(data);
            this.visible(data.blockHide && data.blockHide == true);
        }
        removeButton(data) {
            this.buttons.remove(data);
            this.visible(!this.canClose());
        }
        canClose = ko.computed(function () {
            //var buttons = self.buttons();
            //ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.buttons(), function () { return });

            var k = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.buttons(), function (b) { return b.blockHide && b.blockHide == true });
            return k == null;
        });
        constructor() {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Put the viewmodels inside the same module and import that module.

You are currently creating a new module for each viewmodel/class.

**Update** ***not working see update 2*** If you want to still have multiple files for modules you can merge them into one with the typescript compiler:

```
tsc AppBarViewModel.ts IdentityViewModel.ts
```

Then assuming that the files have the same module "ViewModels" inside of them you can import them with:

```
import vms = module("ViewModels");
```

**Update 2** Merging external modules is currently not supported: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/430782

> Also, to your question about external modules in a single file. 
>   External modules assume that you're using a module loader.  In this
>   case, you'd want your modules to be built into separate source files
>   so that they can be loaded via the module loader.  Building all the
>   modules into one .js file is counter to how these tools work.
>
> I could see wanting to build external modules out of multiple source
>   files, though we don't currently support this and might be a good
>   feature request for the issue tracker, if it's not there already

Vote for this feature here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/759

Comment: You mean to place all my viewmodels in the same file?

Comment: Yup. Same file + same module. This is because the external module import i.e. `module(name:string)` works on filename so the module cannot be distributed over multiple files.

Comment: I started by factoring out all my viewmodels to files to make it easier to maintain. Not going to put it in one file again :(

Comment: Cool, do you know if this can be set insite visual studio using Web Essentials?

Comment: it didnt work. /App/test2.ts(0,0): Cannot compile dynamic modules when
emitting into single file

Comment: Not web essentials. But you can use a prebuild step for that. This would however force you to do a build each time instead of the web essentials way of simply saving a file.

Comment: the error above was from: tsc test1.ts test2.ts --module amd --out test.js

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to turn off AMD support in typescript and instead utilize WebEssentials JS bundle to create a single export for requireJS. To do this I have a "_prebundle.fragment.js" and a "_postbundle.fragment.js" and all the TS compiled code in between:

```
    <file>/js/_prebundle.fragment.js</file>

    <file>/js/file1.js</file>
    <file>/js/file2.js</file>
    <file>/js/file3.js</file>

    <file>/js/_postbundle.fragment.js</file>
```

This creates the following:

```
///#source 1 1 /js/_prebundle.fragment.js
// START _PREBUNDLE.FRAGMENT >>

(function(factory){
    // Support module loading scenarios
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){
        // AMD Anonymous Module
        define(['jquery', 'ga', 'knockout', 'sammy'], factory);
    } else {
        // No module loader (plain <script> tag) - put directly in global namespace
        var global = (window || this);

        global.ma = factory(bootstrap, jQuery, qa, ko, sammy);
    }
})(function($, ga, ko, sammy){
    if (!$) throw new Error('JQuery is a pre-requisite and must be loaded for this component.');
    if (!ga) throw new Error('Google Analytics is a pre-requisite and must be loaded for this component.');
    if (!ko) throw new Error('KnockoutJS is a pre-requisite and must be loaded for this component.');
    if (!sammy) throw new Error('SammyJS is a pre-requisite and must be loaded for this component.');

// END _PREBUNDLE.FRAGMENT
///#source 1 1 /js/File1.js
var ma;
(function (ma) {
    var File1 = (function() {
        function File1() {
            // blah
        }

        return File1;
    })();

    ma.File1 = File1;
})(ma || (ma = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=file1.js.map

///#source 1 1 /js/_postbundle.fragment.js
// START _POSTBUNDLE.FRAGMENT >>

    return ma;
});

// END _POSTBUNDLE.FRAGMENT
```

This produces a single require element and also supports being used without RequireJS, which is nice for when I want to make it public. Additionally, I can bundle up multiple different flavors of my code for use on other pages. Not sure if there's a better way to do this, but this works for me...